# Set files permission after install

Tags: debian, deb

I found this example how to build deb package.

http://blog.noizeramp.com/2005/08/31/packaging-java-applications-for-ubuntu-and-other-debians/

I'm interested how I can set files permission after files are installed?

```
Package: myapp
Version: _version_
Section: web
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Aleksey Gureev 
Description: my first sample application which isn't
 doing anything special.
 .
 And other description goes
 here too.
 .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't. instead, you set the file-permissions while creating the package.

when using `debhelper` for packaging, this would be something like the following in `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms
    find debian -name '*.jar' -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```

and you should follow a [proper Debian packaging tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian) rather than some random 10-year-old blogpost.

Comment: I added the lines but I get this `debian/rules:31: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2`

Comment: Like the error message says, you need to use tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: `debian/rules` is really a `Makefile`, so you need to use *tabs* for indentation